# PHP generate multiple barcodes with labels on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, barcode

I have an application where I need to generate a barcode with labels for some products.

The products are stored in MySQL and so far I can only print one barcode at the time and only with a number under the barcode.

What I would like is to generate them like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GgNm.jpg ( I am sorry for the poor quality ).

I use http://barcodephp.com/ but I am unable to add labels like the price, color, name of the product etc...

I hope you can suggest a way of doing it, or maybe another class which can accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to just generate them as html or can you create PDF documents? I would suggest [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) with the [code128](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script88.php) extension.

Comment: @code1238 I need to print them, so pdfs would be very good. I checked FPDF but among the examples I didn't see any barcode with multiple labels like the picture I posted. Can I accomplish this with MPDF ? My two requirements are: multiple barcodes on the same page to be printed and custom labels. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, the code128 extension can do this. You can loop through and generate one barcode per page, or put multiple barcodes on a single page with this function `$pdf->Code128($x, $y, $code, $w, $h);`

Comment: @Kyro I see, that is partially what I need. My difficulty is to add more labels as in the image, do you think I can generate the labels or I have to add them after the barcode is generated and then print the pdf ?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I read barcode instead of label. You can similarly accomplish this with the combination of `$pdf->SetXY($x,$y)` and `$pdf->Cell($w,$h,$text)`

Comment: You can make a function with some Y position Padding and add it on a while loop. that way you can present them in Descendant order.